# Linq with subquery with Let

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

What I'm trying to get from this Linq query is a list of all Adverts where the most recent associated Log with a `LogType.IsStatus == true` has a `LogType.Name` of either Confirmed or Renewed. To be clear, an Advert has many Logs and each Log has one LogType. So far I have the following, but it's giving me an error System.NotSupportedException on the LastOrDefault.

```
var adverts = (from a in database.Adverts
                      let lastLog = (from l in a.Logs
                                     where l.LogType.IsStatus == true
                                     orderby l.Created_at
                                     select l).LastOrDefault()
                      where (lastLog != null)
                            &&
                            (lastLog.LogType.Name == "Confirmed" || lastLog.LogType.Name == "Renewed")
                            orderby a.Created_at descending
                      select a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LastOrDefault()` is not supported in LINQ to Entities (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx#sectionSection7)).

You can work around this by changing the `order by` clause in your `let` subquery to an `order by` `descending` and then use `FirstOrDefault()` instead.

```
var adverts = (from a in database.Adverts
               let lastLog = (from l in a.Logs
                              where l.LogType.IsStatus == true
                              orderby l.Created_at descending
                              select l).FirstOrDefault()
               where (lastLog != null)
                     &&
                     (lastLog.LogType.Name == "Confirmed" || lastLog.LogType.Name == "Renewed")
                      orderby a.Created_at descending
               select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Query seems to process but I seem to be getting a System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported with this when I come to loop through the Adverts in my view: @foreach (var item in Model). Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Does it say which method isn't supported?  What's this `Model` collection you're iterating over in `foreach (var item in Model)`?

Comment: I have a strongly typed view on Adverts. The exception is snagging on the foreach line if I remove the ToList() part of the query else it snags on the query itself.

Comment: Which method does it say isn't supported?

Comment: Bit difficult to work out. The Inner Exception Source is MySql.Data.Entity. Seems to be something to do with the ToList() method - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555914/foreach-in-linq-result-not-working tried the ticked solution as mention here but when I try to convert the results ToList(), the error strikes!

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing it, it's difficult without having more detail about your model.  The question you linked to suggests that the error is caused by using a custom property in the LINQ query.  Custom properties aren't supported by LINQ to Entities, are you trying to use any here?

Comment: It works if I remove the where clause of the outer query i.e. if I don't use the lastLog variable but as soon as I put the WHERE back in, the NotSupportedException returns. Nightmare!

Comment: Does this query work? `database.Logs.Where(l => l.LogType.Name == "Confirmed" || l.LogType.Name == "Renewed").ToList();`

Comment: Marked as answer as you sorted out my original problem with LastOrDefault(). I managed to sort out the other problems by changing the query to the edited version.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var lookingType = new string[]{"Confirmed", "Renewed"};

var result = database.Adverts
  .Where(entry 
    => entry.Logs.Count() > 0 && entry.Logs.Any(log => log.LogType.IsStatus))
  .Select(entry 
    => new { data = entry, 
       lastLog = entry.Logs.OrderByDescending(log => log.Created_at).First() 
    })
  .Where(entry => lookingType.Contains(entry.lastLog.LogType.Name))
  .Select(entry => entry.data).ToList();
```